# Mixed Content in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have Created App in Ionic But when i call the API then thorugh the using of angular js and ionic but ionic is use https and my api is working on http so my app is not calling the api

My Code is 
 **My Page Code**

```
function ($scope, $stateParams,$state,Login) 
{

     $scope.data={
         'username':'pankeel',
         'password':'1234546'

     }
     $scope.Login_click = function(){

           $state.go('/page2');
          Login.all($scope.data);

     }



}
```

My JS Code

```
angular.module('app.services', [])


.service('Login', ['$http',function($http){
    var api_url='http://phplaravel-125946-364532.cloudwaysapps.com/api/login';

     var ret = {
         all: function(data)
         {

   $http.get(api_url+'/'+data.username + '/' + data.password + '/').then( function(resp){
              return resp.data;
            });
         }
     }
     return ret;


}]);
```

Comment: Check your CORS (also it's a bad idea to send an unencrypted password over the network)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is mixed content type which most browsers block due to security reasons. Please read move about mix contents [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content) about active/passive mixed contents and how we can get they work.

In short, it is not possible due to [Same Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) ,You will need to switch the Ajax requests to https, too.